# Speech recognition and comparison algorithms

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-processing

I am doing several research for a prototype which I will be building. My prototype will consist of single word speech recognition and comparison with a preset recorded words. The prototyped system will then ask the user to say a the word and give a percentage match.

I am hoping to build this prototype with JAVA, however I am not at that stage yet, I am still researching all the available algorithms that exist in order to implement the above. I am seeking some guidance from you experts out there if I am on the right track in looking at the following algorithms to be able to implement the above:

- Acoustic speech recognition
- Hidden Markov Model algorithm
- Discrete Fourier Transform
- Fast Fourier Transform
- The Cross-correlation Algorithm
- The Auto-correlation Algorithm
- The FIR Wiener Filter
- Dynamic Time Warping algorithms
- Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficient

I am not sure if the above is wrong for my project and look into audio fingerprinting.

I am sorry I cannot provide any code for the time being I am still in the theory research part, If this question is not suitable to this forum please let me know so I can delete it and waste no one's time as it is not my intention.

P.S. Keep in mind that since this is only a prototype, moving forward I will research and eventually use any already existing algorithms (API's/Libraries in JAVA) so that is mostly why I am asking if I am on the right track. Many thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do sounds like standard speech recognition. I recommend you check out the Open Source JAVA library from CMU, [Sphinx4](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4). Run the Transcriber or Dialog demos and you can see it in action doing some basic recognition of digits & simple english commands from a small grammar. Note that many of your algorithms listed above, fit into different parts of a speech recognition system (frontend processing, search manager, acoustic scorer, etc)

Check out [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rsingh/homepage/papers/icassp03-sphinx4_2.pdf) for a good overview (and to see how all your algorithms above relate)